# boot microservice not accessible due to laptop security

Tags: spring-boot

I crafted a simple Java8/Eclipse/Maven/spring boot microservice on my own personal laptop ie have admin privileges.
I start it with **java -jar myService.jar** from within a CommandPrompt pane.
I can then access it from my browser at http://localhost:808/myService and receive a ping message as expected.

So far so good.

I've entered this service onto a laptop where I'm just a user - no admin privileges.
It compiles w/o errors. I start it with **java -jar myService.jar** from within a CommandPrompt pane. But from the browser on this machine I get the default whitelabel error page.

I'm thinking this must be some security issue on the 2nd laptop. How can I prove/disprove this assertion? If proven, must I execute temporarily assume Admin rights and launch this jar-file as a service?

-update-

upon closer examination of the startup screens on personal laptop I see mappings occuring...

```
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]-log] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.s.w.c.ContextLoader-prepareWebApplicationContext] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2242 ms
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.s.b.w.s.ServletRegistrationBean-addRegistration] - Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean-configure] - Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean-configure] - Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean-configure] - Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2022-04-29 00:07:51 INFO [o.s.b.w.s.FilterRegistrationBean-configure] - Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2022-04-29 00:07:54 INFO [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping-register] - Mapped "{[/SimpleSpringBootExample/TOD],methods=[GET],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.mybiz.application.controller.BaseController.indexHandlerF(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2022-04-29 00:07:54 INFO [o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping-register] - Mapped "{[/SimpleSpringBootExample/hello],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.mybiz.application.controller.BaseController.indexHandlerB(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

whereas on the other laptop no mapping messages are seen. That'd explain the whitelabel error page - no mapping is occuring. But why?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Comment: Do you see any error in start up logs in cmd pane?

Comment: no errors, starts up fine

Comment: could you deit your question and add the error message on the web browser and also what is the output on you terminal ?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm I would guess that, if it is a privilege issue, it wouldn't render the whitelabel error page, as this is the default page for telling you that the resource / url you try to access was not found. Do you maybe have docker container's running on the port you're trying to access? Had this issue once, as it could happened that a docker container runs on 8080 and your spring application too without the os complaining about an existing port binding